# Account for Basic Authentication info with spring-cloud-gateway

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-cloud

I have set up `spring-cloud-gateway` configuration  but for certain requests I need to account for Basic Authentication credentials, that I read from a configuration file. Though I am not sure how to add them.

This is the config file:

```
public RouteLocator gatewayRoutes(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
    return builder.routes()
                  .route(r -> r.path("/api/m-bank/**") //intercept calls to
                               .uri("http://m-bank.cloud.host/") //Forward to
                               .id("mBankModule"))
```

And these are the Basic Authentication credentials that I need to account for:
[image]

Comment: Do you want the client to send them or the gateway?

Comment: The client will send a request to the gateway program. This request contains an object with the property, its value I need to extract,  inside the gateway - and then use it for filtering.

Comment: the read body predicate is what you want.